# Fastest way to mask a 4D Boolean numpy array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, boolean, mask

Most efficient way to mask a 4D Boolean array with a 2D Boolean mask.

I tried two methods:

A. Reshape mask to 4D and mask

B. Reshape the inverted mask to 4D and product two matrixes

```
import numpy as np
import time

I = 150
J = 2000
K = I
S = 25

matrix_to_mask = np.random.choice(a=[True, False], size=(I, J, K, S))
mask_2d = np.random.choice(a=[True, False], size=(I, S))

t = time.time()
matrix_to_mask[np.tile(mask_2d[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :], (1, J, K, 1))] = False
print("Mask: " + str(time.time() - t)) # 2.77 sec

t = time.time()
a = matrix_to_mask * np.tile(np.invert(mask_2d)[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :], (1, J, K, 1))
print("Product: " + str(time.time() - t)) # 1 sec
```

Is there any other method which will speed up the mask?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use [np.broadcast_to](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) for this. Broadcasting produces a 'virtual' copy of your lower dimension array. E.g. the array is repeated along the dimensions that you specify, but no new memory is allocated, it will only point to the original values. So this is more efficient because it uses less memory and it is faster because it doesn't spend time allocating.

```
t = time.time()
mask_4d = np.broadcast_to(mask_2d, matrix_to_mask.shape)

a = matrix_to_mask * mask_4d
# matrix_to_mask[mask_4d] = False
print("Broadcast: " + str(time.time() - t))
```

So:

```
import numpy as np
import time

I = 150
J = 1000
K = I
S = 25

matrix_to_mask = np.random.choice(a=[True, False], size=(I, J, K, S))
mask_2d = np.random.choice(a=[True, False], size=(I, S))

t = time.time()
matrix_to_mask[np.tile(mask_2d[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :], (1, J, K, 1))] = False
print("Mask: " + str(time.time() - t)) # 2.77 sec

t = time.time()
a = matrix_to_mask * np.tile(mask_2d[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :], (1, J, K, 1))
print("Product: " + str(time.time() - t)) # 1 sec

t = time.time()
mask_4d = np.broadcast_to(mask_2d, matrix_to_mask.shape)

a = matrix_to_mask * mask_4d
# matrix_to_mask[mask_4d] = False
print("Broadcast: " + str(time.time() - t))
```

> Mask: 2.0803346633911133

> Product: 0.8886129856109619

> Broadcast: 0.4950692653656006

That said, I checked the values of the obtained mask and the one you generated with `np.tile(mask_2d[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :], (1, J, K, 1))` and they do not correspond, so something is off. Perhaps check that your method actually produces the mask that you intend, because normally `np.broadcast_to` does exactly what you are looking for, so I would think that that is correct...

Comment: Looks promising. However, only works for the special case of dimension k = I. If I change the k (axis=2) dimension to 10 for example, np.broarcast_to does not work. Basically, the 2d mask is the first and the last axis, not the two last axis of the 4D. np.broadcast_to does not seem to allowed adding axis between the mask_2d.

Comment: to solve my above comment, a reshape has to be done before applying `np.broadcast_to`. mask_4d is now: `np.broadcast_to(mask_2d[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :], matrix_to_mask.shape)`. which adds up to 0.7 sec in my machine. Still a good speed up. Thanks.